# Using docrtrine in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm working on a php project but I have a problem with the database , I use this code to get data from the database :

```
public function getSeenAction(Request $request , $notificationId)
{
    $sessionId = $request->headers->get('SessionID');
    if( $sessionId == null )
    {
        //return new Response("Unauthorized",401);
    }
    $notificationRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MegasoftEntangleBundle:Notification');
    $notification = $notificationRepo->findOneById($notificationId);

    if($notification == null)
    {
        return new Response("Notification not found" ,404);
    }

    $seen = $notification->getSeen();
    $response = new JsonResponse();
    $response->setdata(array('seen'=>$seen));
    $response->setStatusCode(200);
    return $response;
}
```

I tried the same code with other tables and it worked , but whenever I retrive data from the `Notification` table it always give null , although the table contains the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
$notificationRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MegasoftEntangleBundle:Notification');
$notification = $notificationRepo->findAll();
var_dump(notification);
```

Is this code returns you something ? Probably the code of your `NotificationRepository.php` is not good, can you put it on ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `find` instead of `findOneById` if you just want to find record by Id.
On the other hand if you want to use `findOneBy` the passed argument for criteria should be an array.

```
$result = $notificationRepo->find($notificationId);
```

Or

```
$result = $notificationRepo->findOneBy(array('id' => $notificationId));
```

Or

*make sure you have a proper code for `findOneById` in your NotificationRepository.php file*

Then you can check

```
if (!empty($result)) { ... }
```